# OpenGL doesn't work after installing nvidia NVS 310 card with nvidia-375 driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, opengl

we have a 16.04 LTS box that we just installed a nvidia NVS 310 card to replace an AMD firepro 2260 card. The card was detected at the first boot and then we installed nvidia-375 driver by using additional driver utility window.  Later, we found that OpenGL didn't work any more (it worked well with firepro 2260).  Basically, here are the output in a terminal when we log onto that computer via ssh with X11 forwarding.

```
$ glxinfo
name of display: localhost:10.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

$ glxinfo
name of display: localhost:10.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig}

$ glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual}

$ more /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     5.679]
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[     5.679] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     5.679] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     5.679] Current Operating System: Linux czt-softwareserver.nnsd.bnl.gov 4.10.0-27-generic #30~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 16:07:46 UTC 2017 x86_64
[     5.679] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-27-generic root=UUID=1f701163-af3a-4a7e-b564-eca3ac8b6d22 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[     5.679] Build Date: 02 November 2016  10:06:10PM
[     5.680] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[     5.680] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[     5.680]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     5.680] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     5.680] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Jul 23 12:45:19 2017
[     5.680] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     5.680] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     5.682] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[     5.682] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[     5.682] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[     5.682] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[     5.682] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[     5.682] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[     5.682] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     5.682] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     5.682] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     5.682] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     5.682] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     5.682]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.682] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     5.682]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.682] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     5.682]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.682] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     5.682]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.682] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     5.682]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     5.682] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[     5.682] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/
usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     5.682] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[     5.682] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[     5.682] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[     5.682] (II) Loader magic: 0x5633e98abdc0
[     5.682] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     5.682]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     5.682]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[     5.682]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[     5.682]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[     5.682] (++) using VT number 7
[     5.682] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     5.683] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     5.684] (--) PCI:*(0:3:0:0) 10de:107d:10de:1154 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe8000000/134217728,
0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc80/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     5.684] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[     5.684] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[     5.684] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     5.685] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[     5.759] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.759]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.759]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     5.759] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  375.66  Mon May  1 14:28:39 PDT 2017
[     5.759] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     5.759] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[     5.760] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.760]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.760]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.760] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  375.66  Mon May  1 14:03:26 PDT 2017
[     5.760] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[     5.760] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     5.760] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     5.760] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     5.760] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.760]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.760]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.760] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[     5.760] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[     5.760] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[     5.760] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.760]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.760]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.760] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[     5.760] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[     5.761] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[     5.761] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.761] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     5.761] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.761] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     5.761] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     6.188] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:3:0:0
[     6.188] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1 (boot)
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[     6.189] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU NVS 310 (GF119) at PCI:3:0:0 (GPU-0)
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 75.19.9d.00.01
[     6.189] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.189] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): connected
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.203] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.205] (==) NVIDIA(0):
[     6.205] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[     6.205] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[     6.205] (==) NVIDIA(0):
[     6.205] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[     6.205] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
[     6.205] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1600 x 900
[     6.211] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (92, 91); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[     6.211] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[     6.211] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     6.212] (II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[     6.212] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[     6.244] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
[     6.299] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[     6.299] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[     6.299] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     6.299] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[     6.299] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     6.299] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     6.299] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     6.299] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     6.299] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[     6.299] (--) RandR disabled
[     6.302] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[     6.303] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[     6.303] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[     6.335] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[     6.335] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     6.335] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[     6.335] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[     6.336] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.336]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.10.1
[     6.336]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     6.336]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[     6.336] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     6.336] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     6.336] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[     6.336] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[     6.336] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[     6.336] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     6.336] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[     6.336] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[     6.336] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     6.336] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.336] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     6.337] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[     6.337] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     6.337] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     6.337] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     6.337] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[     6.337] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[     6.337] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[     6.337] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     6.337] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event
0"
[     6.337] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[     6.337] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     6.337] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.337] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     6.337] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event9)
[     6.337] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.337] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.338] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event10)
[     6.338] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.338] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.338] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard (/dev/input/event2)
[     6.338] (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     6.338] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard'
[     6.338] (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: always reports core events
[     6.338] (**) evdev: DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[     6.338] (--) evdev: DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Vendor 0x413c Product 0x2107
[     6.338] (--) evdev: DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Found keys
[     6.338] (II) evdev: DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[     6.338] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:413C:21
07.0001/input/input5/event2"
[     6.338] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[     6.338] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     6.338] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.338] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     6.338] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
[     6.338] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[     6.338] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Optical Mouse'
[     6.338] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[     6.338] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[     6.338] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc05a
[     6.338] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found 12 mouse buttons
[     6.338] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[     6.338] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[     6.338] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[     6.338] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[     6.338] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[     6.338] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[     6.338] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[     6.339] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:046D:C0
5A.0002/input/input6/event3"
[     6.339] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[     6.339] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[     6.339] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     6.339] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[     6.339] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     6.339] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     6.339] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[     6.339] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.339] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.339] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line Out (/dev/input/event7)
[     6.339] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.339] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.339] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Front Headphone (/dev/input/event8)
[     6.339] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.339] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.340] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Mic (/dev/input/event5)
[     6.340] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.340] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.340] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line (/dev/input/event6)
[     6.340] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.340] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.341] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event4)
[     6.341] (**) Dell WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     6.341] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Dell WMI hotkeys'
[     6.341] (**) Dell WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[     6.341] (**) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[     6.341] (--) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[     6.341] (--) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[     6.341] (II) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[     6.341] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input7/event4"
[     6.341] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[     6.341] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     6.341] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.341] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     6.769] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[     6.769] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     6.769] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.769] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): connected
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.783] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.960] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[     6.960] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     6.960] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.960] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): connected
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VE205 (DFP-1): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.974] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):

$ lspci -k | grep -iEA5 '3d|vga'
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [NVS 310] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [NVS 310]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller
```

We appreciate any suggestions for further investigation and any solutions to our issues.

Bill

Comment: I just tried logging in locally to the computer and was able to run glxinfo and glxgears without errors.  Still don't know why opengl doesn't work when I ssh in.